# What is the fraction field of formal power series ring over a field $F$？

Tags: ring-theory

> The field of fractions of the formal power series ring $F[[x]]$ over a field $F$ can be obtained by inverting the elements $x$.

Let $R=F[[x]]$. I have difficulty in finding the isomorphism 
$$
\varphi:R[\frac{1}{x}]\to F((x))
$$
where $F((x))$ denotes the fraction field.

I defined $\varphi$ by 
$$
f(x)\mapsto f(x),\quad \frac{1}{x}\mapsto \frac{1}{x},\qquad f(x)\in F[[x]],
$$
which gives a homomorphism.
It can be checked that this is onto. But it seems that this is not one-to-one. <s>Do I miss something here?</s> [How can I modify this homomorphism to get the desired isomorphism?]

Comment: Yes, you are missing something. What is an example of two elements of $R[\frac{1}{x}]$ you think are sent to the same place?

Comment: An alternate approach is to first prove that every element of $R$ can be written uniquely as $x^k f(x)$, where $k\ge0$ and $f(x)\in R$ is an *invertible* formal power series, that is, has an inverse in $R$.

Comment: @GregMartin, do you mean the nonzero elements in $R$? I don't see how $0$ can be written as $x^kf(x)$ where $f(x)$ is a unit in $R$.

Comment: Aha, exactly, the nonzero elements.